# include jsp page based on some condition

Tags: spring-mvc, jstl

I am using spring tags to in my jsp page.

Now I have a situation where I am using form:select for a dropdown.

If I select first value in the dropdown  "normal.jsp" page should be diaplayed. If I select second value "reverse.jsp" page should be displayed.

Both these jsp pages should be displayed in the main page below the dropdown.

What is the best way to achieve this in jsp?

I am trying to use jstl tags but the form is not getting displayed.

This is the code I wrote

```
    <tr>
        <td>Types of Auction :-</td>
        <td>
            <form:select id="auctionType" path="auctionType">
                <form:option value="0" label="Select" />
                <form:options items="${auctionTypesList}" itemValue="auctionTypeId" itemLabel="auctionTypeDesc" />
            </form:select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <c:choose>
                <c:when test="${param.auctionType == 1}">
                    <c:import url="/normalAuction.jsp" var="normal"/>
                </c:when>
                <c:when test="${param.auctionType == 2}">
                    <c:import url="/reverseAuction.jsp" var="reverse"/>
                </c:when>
            </c:choose>
        </td>
    </tr>
```

Can someone let me know where am I going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If your form does not get displayed, perhaps you did not import the spring-mvc form taglib:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
```

This is mandatory as otherwise you will end up with <form:whatever...> tags in your HTML output.

As for importing JSPs based on a request parameter, that would be better handled in your controller by returning different views based on user input as this is actually a controller task more than a view one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using expression language `${}` in your page. Check if you included the tag lib

`<%@ page isELIgnored ="true|false" %>`  in your header. True means that EL is ignored and false will not ignore the EL tags. So put `false`

Also when you use `chose` tag, and `when` as its sub tag, these has to be a `otherwise` tag.

```
 <choose>
    <when condition>Page_1.jsp
    </when>
    <when condition_2>Page_other.jsp
    </when>
    <otherwise>Page_2.jsp
    </otherwise>
 </chose>
```